# How do I have github build a project page automatically from a folder in the master branch?

Tags: git, github, configuration, github-pages

I have a [github](https://github.com/) project that has its own project page. In the `master` branch of this project is a directory `html` containing the files for the project page. So, e.g. the project `https://github.com/con-f-use/foobar` has a file `./html/index.html` that is reachable over `https://con-f-use.github.io/foobar/index.html`.

So far, when I change the html in the `master` branch, usually I update the project page (which git requires to be in its own branch `gh-pages`) via the command:

```
 git subtree push --prefix html origin gh-pages   # From master branch
```

I would like to configure git, to do that updating automatically, every time when I push something to `master`. Optionally it would be nice, but ultimately unimportant, if it worked the other way around, too. So I can push to `gh-pages` and master gets the changes in `./html` without me manually fiddling around. I'm aware that git allows one to specify post-commit scripts. I could just put the above command in one of those scripts. The problem with that is, I'd have to manually specify this script for every local clone of the repository. I'd rather have github do it non-locally.

**Is there a way to configure github to keep the the `./html/` directory from the `master` branch automatically up to date with the root `./` of the `gh-pages` branch (and vice verso) and do it without me changing local git configuration?**

So what I want, is, that whenever I push to `gh-pages`, the `./html`in the `master` branch gets the changes as well. Likewise, when I push new changes in the `./html` directory of `master`, these changes should automatically propagate to `gh-pages` root `./` directory.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution, similar to `subtrees` from the OP is:

```
git submodule add -b gh-pages git@github.com:con-f-use/foobar.git ./html
```

So the steps:

- Make sure the contents of the `./html` folder is in `gh-pages` on the remote and is up to date
- Delete the `./html` folder in `master`, commit and push
- Add the `gh-pages` branch as submodule with the above command and commit and push

But that needs a `git pull --recurse-submodules` followed by `git submodule update --remote --recursive` and a commit on `master` to update.

Not that still requires running commands other than a single push.